What is a "Property" and what is "Induction Principle"? - Logic and Structure, Dirk van Dalen
Hello I've had some trouble understanding the following theorem in Logic and Structure, Dirk van Dalen:
Let $A$ be a property, then $A(\phi)$ holds for all $\phi\in\mathrm{PROP}$ if
(i) $A(p_i)$, for all $i$, and $A(\bot)$,
(ii) $A(\phi), A(\varphi) \;\Rightarrow\; A(\phi\mathbin{\square}\varphi)$
(iii) $A(\phi) \;\Rightarrow\; A(\neg\phi)$
Firstly, what is a property $A(\;\;)$? Is it a property like being blue? Additionally, is this theorem only saying that once a property holds true for enough cases i), ii), iii) it holds true for all prepositions? I'm quite confused on that, since I'm currently understanding a property as being a property in normal language, i.e., being blue, but from there I cannot understand how any common property like "$\mathrm{blue}(\;\;)$" can hold for every single proposition in $\mathrm{PROP}$. I cannot come up with an $A(\;\;)$ that satisfies the hypothesis of the theorem, and cannot understand why given that it does, that the conclusion is useful.
Edit: Based off the comments, assuming the only properties that satisfy the hypothesis are those that are "evidently" true for all propositions because of the way they are formed by definition, how do we use this theorem beyond proving that all propositions have those "evident properties"? Or is its use only in doing just that?
I feel as though I am missing something quite clearly, any help would be appreciated as this is my first time trying to study logic alone, on my own (having only taken a maths proofs class before).

A property is a... property suitable for the domain of objects of our theory. "To be even" for numbers, "to be continuous" for real functions, "to be well-formed" for the expressions of the language.

In the case above, regarding formulas, to have an even number of parentheses, half of which right and half left.

@MauroALLEGRANZA The domain here clearly consists of well-formed formulas already. A better example would be "doesn't contain $\neg$", or "has an even number of $\to$" (but those do not hold for all formulas).

Okay yes that makes a bit more sense, so then the only properties that fulfill (i), (ii), and (iii) are those which are things like "to have an even # of parentheses"? If that is the case, then is the theorem's only use is to justify that all propositions in PROP have such properties?

Yes, but just because the property holds of all formulas doesn't mean it's trivial (wherever you draw the line anyway). For example, we can use induction on formulas to show properties like "can be rewritten equivalently using just $\neg$ and $\to$".

@NatalieClarius Thank you that clears some stuff up, I see the motivation now.

Yikes! What a bizarre way to state the principle of induction. I prefer: For every subset P of N, if  (0 in P) and (for every x in P, we also have S(x) in P) then P = N. (From Peano's Axioms.)

A property is a... property suitable for the domain of objects of our theory: in this case the domain of the expressions of the formal language
"To be even" is a property applying to numbers, "to be continuous" applies to real functions, "to be well-formed" applies to expressions.
In the case above, regarding Induction, "to have an even number of parentheses, half of which right and half left" is a property of expressions of the formal language.
